# Could not find API Controller from angular service

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have tried to call api controller form angular and got the following error in console.

console error

```
POST http://localhost:53856/api/Form 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my module

```
var app = angular.module('AutobotModule', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/Home", {
        templateUrl: "/Home.html",
        controller: "HomeController"
    })
    .when("/Form", {
        templateUrl: "/Views/BasicSetup/FormSetup.html",
        controller: "FormController"
    })
.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/Home" })
```

});

this is my controller

```
(function () {
var FormController = function ($scope, formService, $log, $routeParams, $location) {

    $scope.save = function (form) {
        formService.save(form)
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $location.path("/Form");
            });
    };

    $scope.Title = "Form Setup";
};
app.controller("FormController", ["$scope", "formService", "$log", "$routeParams", "$location", FormController]);
}());
```

I create this service called FormService.js to call the api controller

```
(function () {
var formService = function ($http, $q, $log) {
    var cachedform;

    var save = function (form) {
        return $http.post("api/Form", form)
        .then(function (result) {
            $log.info("Insert Successful");
            cachedform = result.data;
            return result;
        });
    };

    return {
        save: save
    };
};

var module = angular.module("AutobotModule");

module.factory("formService", ["$http", "$q", "$log", formService]);
}());
```

api controller

```
 public class FormController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/Form")]
    public int Post(FormDAO p)
    {
        return new FormBLL().Insert(p);
    }
}
```

web apiconfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be needed, but have you tried adding `[HttpPost]` as an attribute to your method?

Comment: @Deba make sure you have an API project running on this port //localhost:53856 or right click on API solution and click start as startup project and than check port is same as you have defined in question

Comment: looks like you are trying to mix convention-based and attribute routing. if you are using `Route` attribute then you need the `[HttpPost]` attribute in this case as looks like you want a POST request. if using attribute routing you also need to make sure that you have enabled it in web api config. `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`